# Word VBA count replacements made

Tags: vba, ms-word

How can I simulate the dialog box that pops up after you do a replace all into a VBA code for Word 2007?

[image: Before Replacement]

[image]

What i want is to get the return value of the replacement count that happened after the replace all button was clicked (in this case the value 9 replacements).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here ya go: [How to find out, using VBA, how many replacements Word made during a Find & Replace All](http://word.mvps.org/FAQs/MacrosVBA/GetNoOfReplacements.htm)

Comment: Thanks Otaku. I guess there really is no easy way to simulate that. Glad you pointed me to the right direction. Its clear to me now. ;)